# Where to find interviewees for questions about user experience in open source software?

Tags: software-development

We’re two information systems students at Uppsala university, Sweden, currently working on our bachelor’s thesis. The aim of our paper is to investigate usability in open-source software and conduct a qualitative study on the subject. To do this in a satisfactory manner we hope to examine a couple of open source projects and interview it’s main developers with the intent of gaining knowledge about development within the context of usability in open-source software. The interviews will be done via e-mail and all participants are anonymous. The software itself will be heuristically evaluated and the result will be analyzed together with the answers from the interviews. Our time span is quite limited and our goal is to have completed the interviews within 1-4 weeks.

Where would be a good place to look for these developers to interview?

Thank you and best regards,
Robert & David

Comment: Hey there! Unfortunately, you're probably not going to find much luck here. As a site, we don't generally allow requests like this, but I am sure that many users would love to help out either in [Stack Exchange Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com) or [Stack Overflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com). Just try not to advertise excessively. You can also try the forums at Reddit and other internet communities as well. Lastly, be sure to stick around! We'd be more than happy to hear whatever questions or answers you get in the course of your studies!

Answer (score 2):

You could contact the developers of active open source projects directly. Any serious project shouldn't make it hard to find contact information.

A good website to find active open source projects is [GitHub](https://github.com/explore).